# Azure Architecture Implementation Ideas

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

We've designed a Data Architecture for our client on Azure wherein, We ingest the sources into a Raw Layer consisting of a Azure SQL Database. This Azure SQL Database acts as a Source Mirror and Has Near Real time sync enabled.

We also have an ODS Layer which is populated from the Previously mentioned Azure SQL Database (Source Mirror) as per the given Data Model. This Layer should ideally take anywhere between 30mins and 1 Hour to Load.

May I Know How Do I Handle the Concurrent Writes and Reads from the Raw Layer (Azure SQL Database, Source Mirror) ? It Syncs every 5 mins with the Sources but also read every 30mins - 1 Hour for ODS Layer.

I've to Use Azure Data Factory to Implement my Data Loads

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Azure Data Factory platform is best fit for such scenarios. Its a cloud-based ETL and data integration tool that lets you build data-driven processes for managing data transportation and data transformation at scale. You can use Azure Data Factory to design and plan data-driven processes (also known as pipelines) that may consume data from a variety of sources. With data flows or computing services like Azure HDInsight Hadoop, Azure Databricks, and Azure SQL Database, you can design sophisticated ETL processes that convert data graphically.

> When using control flow, you can use a GetMetadata activity to get a
> list of files in a storage account, then pass that list to a for each
> activity with the Sequential flag set to false to process all files
> concurrently (in parallel) up to the maximum batch size according to
> the activities defined in the for each loop.

Here, is the Microsoft Official Document for the Azure Datafactory Connectors Overview | [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-overview)